# How to uninstall the default Videos application - Freya

Tags: release-freya, applications, videos, audience

I tried to use following command to remove the default Videos application. but it doesn't work, could you help me out? thanks in advice

```
sudo apt-get purge totem
```

Thanks 
Yuhua

Comment: The default Video player always crash. This commend is working for me to remove the default Video player from Loki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To uninstall the default videos application (audience) run the following in a terminal.

```
sudo apt remove audience
```

Remember to mark as answer if it works

Comment: I'm wondering why sudo apt remove io.elementary.videos didn't work. How did you get the corresponding name.